Game+ Save for Zoids Legacy on VBA
I'm trying to use the Visual Boy Advance (VBA) emulator to play Zoids Legacy, and I've completed the game using its save states. However, Zoids has a Game+ option once you save in-game after the credits roll, which I can't do using the emulator save states.
Is there a workaround to save in-game to continue the story using VBA? As it stands, the in-game save option simply states "Failed to save data. Try to save it again." I can save state at the save option, but not after due to the error.

Are you able to save the game when you aren't using savestates?

No, as it's on an emulator it doesn't appear to work, or it's possible I don't know how to do that. I'm not very knowledgeable about emulators to begin with.
